# What word can be used to refer to things that annoy us?

Tags: word-request

I am stuck finding a word referring to annoying things. Can you suggest some? Thank you.

From comment: I'm looking for a noun actually, some noun that can generally refer to all those bad experience I have got in the day.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Or are you just looking for a broad term?

Comment: This is a very open question. If you google "annoying synonym" you will get a list like this: : irritating, infuriating, exasperating, maddening, trying, tiresome, troublesome, bothersome, irksome, vexing, vexatious, galling, provoking, displeasing; awkward, difficult, inconvenient;
informal, aggravating, pesky, cussed, confounded, infernal, pestiferous, plaguy, pestilent. I am voting to close this question as too broad: if you would like to specify a particular type of annoying thing that you would like a word for, please edit your question.

Comment: I'm looking for a noun actually, some noun that can generally refer to all those bad experience I have got in the day. Next time I'll make my question more specific. Thank you guys.

Comment: Why is this an unacceptably "open" question?  Can a person not just want a word that means what they describe?

Comment: Hmm... the question is "What word can be used to refer to things that annoy us?" but in your comment, you said "some noun that can generally refer to all those bad experience I have got in the day". They aren't the same, in my opinion. (BTW, a more specific example may lead to better and more specific words.)

Comment: @Dam Why not take the question to mean what it says on plain reading? ELLs often don't know that a given word has a form that will serve their purpose. *Annoyances* is a term that refers to (names) annoying things. Someone else might give an expanded answer that could be more useful than my simple one. But maybe mine is just what's requested. There can be no more specific answer, certainly! :-)

Answer (score 5):

> Annoyance

noun
1.
a person or thing that annoys; nuisance:
*Unwanted visitors are an annoyance.*

--http://www.dictionary.com/browse/annoyance

An example to match your request:

*It's hard to keep a positive attitude when we face a series of annoyances every day.*

Others include *inconvenience, vexation, irritant, bother, problem.*

Comment: +1 This would be the big category that everything falls into. For animate things, "pests" can also be used: "my sister is a pest", "mosquitoes are pests that I hate".

Comment: "Nuisance" also works.

Comment: I think it's highly misleading to post this as an "answer" to OP's word request. Whilst it's true that the singular usage *Unwanted visitors are an annoyance* is perfectly natural, it's actually much more often used to mean *the **state** of being annoyed*, not *a thing which **causes** annoyance*. And in OP's specific *plural* context it's not at all likely to be used.

Comment: @Fum My reasoning is that the OP might have been unaware of the noun form. It's not supplied by looking up *annoying* in a typical dictionary. Yes, it's perfectly natural, no matter if it's more commonly used in the other sense. A multitude of annoyances seems likely enough to me to be called *annoyances.* It remains that nothing is more precisely annoying than an annoyance. I certainly did not intend to mislead and hope I didn't.